# Multiple SecurityScheme for swagger/open-api

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui

I am facing a problem with the swagger UI 3 and the generated shcema.yml file
Currently, I have the configuration similar to this one:

```
@SecurityScheme(name = "security-oauth", type = SecuritySchemeType.OAUTH2,
        flows = @OAuthFlows(
                authorizationCode = @OAuthFlow(
                        authorizationUrl = "${authUrl}",
                        tokenUrl = "${tokenUrl}",
                        scopes = {}
                )
        )
)
```

This works as intended. Now, I want to add another `@SecurityScheme` so that I can also pass a cookie to the FE (an Angular App) and to get it back. However, the swagger UI and the generation for the schema.yml file fails.

```
@SecuritySchemes( {
    @SecurityScheme(name = "security-oauth", type = SecuritySchemeType.OAUTH2,
        flows = @OAuthFlows(
                authorizationCode = @OAuthFlow(
                        authorizationUrl = "${authUrl}",
                        tokenUrl = "${tokenUrl}",
                        scopes = {}
                )
        )
    )
    }
)
```

With the annotation like this, the schema.yml is missing the `secuirySchema` part:

```
securitySchemes:
    security-oauth:
      type: oauth2
      flows:
        authorizationCode:
```

Am I missing something or is there a bug in the generation where it does not properly handle the `@SecuritySchemes` annotation?

Comment: Try using two `@SecurityScheme` annotations as shown here: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/blob/master/modules/swagger-jaxrs2/src/test/java/io/swagger/v3/jaxrs2/annotations/security/SecurityTest.java#L161-L167

Comment: @Helen Thanks, I will try that and see if it works. I still find it odd that the official way (of using the wrapper) does not.